# Matlab zoom listener in a GUI

Tags: matlab, plot, zooming

I have a gui that consists of a plot and a static text in MATLAB.

I want to have a zoom listener on the plot so that i can update the static text with the magnification. Is there anyway that i can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Script file (or you can do this as a nested function, whatever you feel like):

```
f = figure(1);
z = zoom(f);
imshow(ones(400));
xlim = get(gca,'XLim');
t = text(150,150,'hello','fontsize',4000/(xlim(2)-xlim(1)));
set(z,'ActionPostCallback',@(obj,event_obj)testcallback(obj,event_obj,t));
```

Function `testcallback.m` file:

```
function testcallback(obj,event_obj,t)
    xlim = get(event_obj.Axes,'XLim');
    set(t,'fontsize',4000/(xlim(2)-xlim(1)));
end
```

Output:

[image]

Also, here's the matlab documentation on the `zoom` object if you want to change directly how the zoom function works or mess with some other things:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zoom.html

**EDIT:** 
Lastly, you can implement this as a nested function to pass the text object. Save this as `testfunction.m` and then run it in the terminal by simply typing `testfunction`:

```
function testfunction

    f = figure(1);
    z = zoom(f);
    imshow(ones(400));
    xlim = get(gca,'XLim');
    t = text(150,150,'hello','fontsize',4000/(xlim(2)-xlim(1)));
    set(z,'ActionPostCallback',@testcallback);

    function testcallback(obj,event_obj)
        xlim = get(event_obj.Axes,'XLim');
        set(t,'fontsize',4000/(xlim(2)-xlim(1)));
    end

end
```

Comment: is there anyway i can pass in handles so i can access the static text?

Comment: I modified it. You might need to test it and tweak it, but it's one way you can do it. Also, if you want to do it through `addlistener` I think you'd have to find out which value is being changed in the axes and then add a callback to when that value is being changed (or something along those lines). I think doing a simple callback this way is easier though.

Comment: Another thing is that if you implement this as a nested function then you can access the text object directly. I updated it again to show what I mean.

Comment: Can you possibly explain what the: set(z,'ActionPostCallback',@(obj,event_obj)testcallback(obj,event_obj,t)); line means? mainly the @(obj,event_obj)testcallback(obj,event_obj,t) part

Comment: @clairharrison My understanding is that whenever you set the callback like that, you it will take in `(obj,event_obj)` as like automatic arguments, i.e. these are sent as arguments to the callback function automatically by Matlab. These arguments are used to obtain what object called the callback and some other stuff. You can basically append an argument that's already located in your workspace. In this case, `t` is a text object that already exists, so doing the above sort of appends it the arguments that it sends to the callback.

Comment: That explanation kind of sucked, but just mess around with it to see how it works. Try out writing a function like `function test = (a,b,c)`, then make a function handle out of it by doing `test_handle = @(a,b)test(a,b,3)`; Then call the function by `test_handle(1,2)`. If you debug the function file you'll find that `(1,2,3)` have been passed as arguments. You can try this again with `test_handle(5,6)` and you'll find that `(5,6,3)` are the arguments, etc...