# MATLAB - How to zoom in to mouse position

Tags: matlab, zooming, mouse, ginput

have an image that I would like to zoom in/out when I left/Right-click a point on the image but I do not want to do it using the magnifying glass. Basically, I need a script for what I said above. I have come up with the following script but it only zooms in/out to the center not to the position that I click on.

And if you are asking why I am getting the clicked position using `ginput` the answer is, I am planning to use this script to edit a binary image! I have removed the lines corresponding to the binary image editing part to avoid any confusion.

```
hFi= figure; imshow(e);

button=0;

while button~=2
    % Get the mouse position on the axes (needed for binary image editing) and button number
    [y,x,button]=ginput(1);

    % Get the mouse position on the figure
    position=get(hFi,'CurrentPoint')

    % Set 'CurrentPoint' to the mouse position that was just captured
    set(hFi,'CurrentPoint',position)

    % Determine if it is a zoom-in or zoom-out
    if button==1
        zoom(2);
    elseif button==3
        zoom(0.5);
    end

end
```

I think the command `set()` does not do anything here but I saw someone suggested that in a forum. Sorry if that looks dumb!

Comment: You should use a callback to do this. I answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083360/matlab-zoom-listener-in-a-gui/19083756#19083756) for text, but it could be adapted for images.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that and let you know.

Comment: After rereading your question, you might want to look specifically at a mouse click listener/callback. Something along the lines of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2769339/1346994). Callbacks in MATLAB are functions which are called after an event (i.e. the `WindowButtonDownFcn` gets called after a mouse click). This is the route to go to deal with events like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after playing around with `imshow` and reading through the documentation on internet, I finally came up with what I had been looking for. Thanks to everyone who suggested some ideas, especially ASantosRibeiro who gave me the idea of changing the axis limits.

Basically, I used a combination of commands `zoom` and `xlim`/`ylim`. Therefore, the final code would look like:

```
hFi= figure; h=imshow(e);

button=0;
zlvl=1;
xl = get(gca,'xlim');
xlen = size(e,2);
yl = get(gca,'ylim');
ylen = size(e,1);

while button~=2
    % Get the mouse position on the axes (needed for binary image editing) and button number
    [y,x,button]=ginput(1);

    % Determine if it is a zoom-in or zoom-out
    if button==1
        zlvl = zlvl*2;
        zoom(2);
    elseif button==3
        zlvl = zlvl/2;
        if zlvl<1, zlvl=1; end % No zoom level smaller than 1
        zoom(0.5);
    end

    % Change the axis limits to where the mouse click has occurred
    % and make sure that the display window is within the image dimensions
    xlimit = [x-xlen/zlvl/2+0.5 x+xlen/zlvl/2+0.5];
    if xlimit(1)<0.5, xlimit=[0.5 xlen/zlvl+0.5]; end
    if xlimit(2)>0.5+xlen, xlimit=[xlen-xlen/zlvl+0.5 xlen+0.5]; end
    xlim(xlimit);

    ylimit = [y-ylen/zlvl/2+0.5 y+ylen/zlvl/2+0.5];
    if ylimit(1)<=0.5, ylimit=[0.5 ylen/zlvl+0.5]; end
    if ylimit(2)>=0.5+ylen, ylimit=[ylen-ylen/zlvl+0.5 ylen+0.5]; end
    ylim(ylimit);
end
```

This code lets you zoom in/out when you use `ginput` and you need to use `imshow` to keep the aspect ratio of image fixed. This becomes very helpful when you need to read coordinates of image pixels and zoom in/out as well. It zooms in when the user left-clicks and zooms out when the user left-clicks. If the middle button is clicked the while loop ends. Other buttons can be added to perform desired operations. For example, I added a few lines of code to edit binary images.

I would like to know your thoughts and if there is any way to make this code more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a matrix as you are asking for the y and x values.
In this way a simple answer would be to display a smaller, or a larger range of values.

Let A be your matrix.

```
    A=rand(1000,1000);
figure,
h=imagesc(A)
axis off
axis image
colormap('gray')
A_range=size(A);
A_zoom=1;
while true

    [y,x,button]=ginput(1)

    A_center=[x,y];

    if button==1
        A_zoom=A_zoom/2;
    elseif button==3
        A_zoom=A_zoom*2;
    end

    axis([max(x-A_range(1)*A_zoom,1), min(x+A_range(1)*A_zoom,A_range(1)), ...
        max(y-A_range(2)*A_zoom,1), min(y+A_range(2)*A_zoom,A_range(2))])
end
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the code. But when I try your script it does not zoom in. For zoom-out, it only crops the image.

Comment: ups. opposite zooms. should be corrected now. Yes the goal is to crop. if you want differently you need to interpolate which will create artificial data.

Comment: this way you will see it as a normal zoom of matlab.

Comment: Now it does crop the image but how about the zoom? When I use the `imshow` command instead of `imagesc` it does not seem to zoom in/out. Do I need to re-size the image afterwards?

Comment: Now it is closer to what I have in mind but still does not do it the same way that the magnifying glass does it for `imshow`. Anyway, I really appreciate your time.

Comment: @Omid you left me curious. this should be it.

Comment: For `imagesc` it works as expected. For `imshow` it is different because `imshow` keeps the aspect ratio of the image is fixed. The way you are displaying the zoomed-in image is different from the way that the magnifying glass does it on `imshow`. If you try your code with `imshow` you will see that difference.

Comment: Forgot to add. you should use imagesc. imshow is too restricted and  should not be what you want. I do not see a point of using imshow. good luck

Comment: The point with `imshow` is it displays true pixel positions of the image and I need that data for binary image editing. If I use `imagesc` with `ginput` the position that `ginput` gives me would not be the pixel position.